# Branch and bound stanford slides doubt

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

On the 6th slide at https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/bb_slides.pdf, while defining L2 and U2, why are we taking min for both?

Comment: Please be more explicit with your question: in particular, giving the general context and the definitions of $L_2$ and $U_2$ only takes a few lines, and makes this question potentially useful to more people than just yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question to make the question self-contained and provide all relevant context (the definitions of L2 and U2, etc.).  People shouldn't have to click to look on a separate page to understand what you are asking; and if that link stops working, we want the question to still be understandable.  Finally, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slides are correct: remember that we are trying to find a bound on the *optimal value* of $f$, which is defined as 
$$\Phi_\mbox{min}({\cal Q}_\mbox{init}) =\min_{x\in{\cal Q}_{\tiny\mbox{init}}}f(x)$$

To find that minimum, we *approximate it* by upper and lower bounds $\Phi_\mbox{ub}$ and $\Phi_{\mbox{lb}}$. Let's concentrate on $\Phi_{\mbox{ub}}$. Note that if ${\cal Q}={\cal Q}_1\cup{\cal Q}_2$, then *both*
$$ \min(\Phi_{\mbox{ub}}(\cal Q_1),\Phi_{\mbox{ub}}(\cal Q_2))\geq\Phi_\mbox{min}(\cal Q)$$
and
$$ \max(\Phi_{\mbox{ub}}(\cal Q_1),\Phi_{\mbox{ub}}(\cal Q_2))\geq\Phi_\mbox{min}(\cal Q)$$

But we might as well take $\min$, since that is the value that is closer to the *global minimum* $\Phi_\min(\cal Q)$!

In fact, taking the minimum is going to be *necessary* if we want the branch and bound method to converge to the minimum as we sub-divide $\cal Q$ into smaller and smaller pieces.